# Why does my CodeIgniter 4 shopping cart code only return 1 item when the totalItems() method shows more than 1?

Tags: php, shopping-cart, codeigniter-4

The program works just fine, but when i add this cart it only return 1 items. I checked the cart also using `$cart->totalItems();` and the result is more than 1, yet i got only 1 item when it got printed out on `print_r($data)` .

Controller
Cart.php

> function check()

```
public function check()
    {
        $cart = \Config\Services::cart();

        $response = $cart->contents();
        $data = json_encode($response,  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        echo '<pre>';

        print_r($data);


        echo '</pre>';

        echo $cart->totalItems();
    }
```

> function add()

```
public function add()
    {
        $cart = \Config\Services::cart();


        $data = array(
            'id'      => 'sku_1234ABCD',
            'qty'     => 1,
            'price'   => '19.56',
            'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
            'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
        );
        $cart->insert($data);

        echo "Your Item has been added to the cart <br/>";

        // return redirect()->to(base_url('main/home'));
    }
```

I have tried using loop, but it just returned the same items. I'm using codeigniter 4 cart libraries. Can you guys help me how to solve this?

Comment: Are you adding the same item several times? The cart will only show the one item with a QTY of XX - What does `$cart->totalItems();` show?

Comment: oh it shows the total result of items, but when i add an item to the cart it will be increase. i mean the `totalItems()`

Comment: Sorry Andra - **Some libraries from CodeIgniter 3 no longer exists in Version 4.** For all these libraries, you have to find a new way to implement your functions. These libraries are Calendaring, FTP, Javascript, `Shopping Cart`, Trackback, XML-RPC /-Server, and Zip Encoding. This cannot be used per [Codeigniters Upgrade Page](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_4xx.html)